# Code after my for loop won't work, the print statement after the for loop does not get printed

Tags: c++

My code does not continue after the for loop, the cursor just remains there blinking.
I tried it on multiple compilers still same problem.

```
   Input:
   3 50
   60 20
   100 50
   120 30
```

when I give this input it take 3 values, than does not print the statement after the for loop. It just pauses. :(

[here is the for loop (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fmMY.png)

This is the problem I face.
[not working after taking input (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKqiB.png)

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;

double get_optimal_value (int capacity, vector<int> weights, 
                              vector<int> values, int n){
    std::cout<<"we are in the function";
    double value = 0.0;
    int current_weight = 0;

    vector<double> v_by_w(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        v_by_w[i] = values[i] / weights[i];

    std::cout<<"printing the v/w elements";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout<< v_by_w[i] << " ";

    while( current_weight < capacity ) {
        int maxi = std::max_element(v_by_w.begin(),v_by_w.end()) - 
        v_by_w.begin();

        if((capacity - current_weight) > weights[maxi]){
            current_weight += weights[maxi];
            value = values[maxi];
        } else
            value += v_by_w[maxi]*(capacity - current_weight);

        v_by_w[maxi] = -1;
    }

    return value;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int capacity;
    char ch;
    std::cin >> n >> capacity;
    vector<int> values(n);
    vector<int> weights(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout<<"hello "<<i ;
        std::cin >> values[i] >> weights[i];
    }

    std::cout<<"we took the values"; //why won't this print?

    double optimal_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values, n);

    std::cout.precision(10);
    std::cout << optimal_value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to print that we took the input after taking the input.

please let me know why does this happen. What can I do to prevent it.

This will really help me :)

Comment: Your `while` loop won't terminate if `current_weight` doesn't exceed `capacity`. `current_weight` gets incremented only in `if` condition and in `else` condition, only `value` is getting changed. Is this how it should be? I would use a debugger to step through and find why it's not breaking

Comment: It doesn't print because you don't flush the output buffer until after `get_optimal_value`, and that function is stuck in an infinite loop. Add `<< std::endl`, or print to `std::cerr`.

Comment: I have to go to work, but your problem is inside `while()` loop, it is endless. Explain little better what is your program suppose to do.

Comment: awesome i tried all your solutions :)
firstly

Comment: firstly i removed the while loop and ran the program it printed the line i wanted.
Secondly i used std::endl keeping the while loop and it also worked fine. (full program works here)

logically the while loop is fine. I dont know exactly why does it become an infinite loop when i don't flush the output buffer.

Also assuming its an infinite while loop, then it should print all the couts.
this does not happen, i guess its mostly due to flushing output buffer.
Would love to learn about this :)
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code below:

```
int main()
{
int n;
int capacity;
char ch;
std::cin >> n >> capacity;
vector<int> values(n);
vector<int> weights(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cout<<"hello "<<i ;
    std::cin >> values[i] >> weights[i];
}

std::cout<<"we took the values"; //this is getting printed after taking 2n input from keyboard
}
```

Below is a explanation of sample run of your program:

On running the code, I get empty console window. At this point, the line below is expecting two input from the keyboard:
std::cin >> n >> capacity;
So I give the below input(2 space 3 enter)
2 3 // please note with this input 2 is assigned to variable n and 3 is assigned to variable capacity

Now the program execution control enters your for-loop and print the line below
code: std::cout<<"hello "<

output hello 0
Now enter your two input:output hello 011 12 (11 space 12 enter) // after hitting enter 11 is assigned to values[0] and 12 is assigned to weights[0]

this triggers next iteration of loop, console window looks as shown below:

hello 011 12
hello 1
now enter your two input:hello 113 14(13 space 14 enter) // after hitting enter 13 is assigned to values[1] and 14 is assigned to weights[1]

Now loop is terminated and your text after loop is print on the screen.

Catch here is each iteration of for-loop requires two int input from console (std::cin >> values[i] >> weights[i];)

Comment: Hey, yes i agree with you here. :)
I too ran only this part of the program and it takes in everything and prints out the line just fine.

However if you run the whole program it does not print the line after the for loop
Flushing the output buffer did do the trick for me :)